# How can I configure Diablo 3 to remember my health bar settings?

Tags: diablo-iii

Every time I launch the game, I have to turn this setting back on.

Comment: You should not have to keep doing this.  It should save the setting.

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: Nope, using a PC.  Also, good to know that it's saving properly for others; I'll play around w/ my setup

Comment: Worth noting that this preference should save just fine under OS X (it does for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging out and exiting to the main screen before completely exiting the game.

[world-of-warcraft](/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) used to do this with some settings.  Worth a shot.

Comment: Turns out this was the culprit; I was uncleanly closing the game some how.  (The keys have been unbound for a while)

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you aren't toggling them on/off with the bound keys during gameplay.